# Life of an object inside an Action MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dispose

When is an object of a class inside an action of a controller disposed in ASP .NET MVC.?

Comment: could you elaborate with some code?

Comment: does the object you want to dispose implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: No its a simple class object I am using. I am planning to dispose it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you explicitly dispose it, then it's disposed whenever the garbage collector runs.  There is no way to know when that will happen.  That's assuming there is no other reference to the object being stored somewhere.

NOTE: "Dispose" here means to cleanup resources like connections or unmanaged memory.  This is done by the object implementing IDisposable.

The object itself will not be deleted from memory (even if disposed) until the garbage collector runs.  It is not advisable to try to force garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Can you please let me know how to dispose an object manually inside Action.

Comment: +1. Note that if "disposed" used as simply "removed from memory" and not as "when `IDisposable` will be disposed" than only second part applies (removed from memory when GC feels so).

Comment: If the object implements IDisposable, then you call .Dispose on it.  Or, you can implicitly dispose of it by wrapping it in a using block.  Also, if you mean when will the memory be collected, then you cannot manually force that with any reliability (nor should you, that's bad practice).

Comment: @G.R you shouldn't be concerned about that.

Comment: @Mystere the object I am talking about is a huge one for showing a menu.So is it good to manually dispose it inside the action?.Will it help to improve any performance i mean ram usage of Web Server?

Comment: @G.R - Huge?  I doubt it's huge..  Huge would be hundreds of megabytes.  This probably nowhere near as big as you think it is.  Just don't worry about it unless you discover it to be a problem.  Messing with garbage collection has its own repercussions on performance.